# Area under 3 curves

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> > Question: Find an expression, in terms of $p$, for the area bounded by $y = 8x$, $y = px$ and $y = x^{-2}$, where p
> >     is a constant, and $0 < p < 8$.
> >
> > Here is a picture: [image]

What I have done is found the intersection as $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x={p^{\frac{-1}{3}}}$ but I have trouble setting up the integral how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A(p) = \int_0^{1/2}(8 - p)x\,dx + \int_{1/2}^{p^{1/3}}(x^{-2}-px)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

1. Find all $3$ points of intersection in the diagram
2. Split the integral into $3$ areas, where the first is an integral of $8x$, the second is an integral of $x^{-2}$ and the third is the area of the triangle that isn't being measured

Answer (score 1):

Integrate over the regions before the second intersection ( $[0,1/2]$ ) and after the second intersection ( $[1/2,p^{-1/3}]$ ) separately.

In the first region, the area is bounded by $8x$ and $px$ and in the second, it is bounded by $x^{-2}$ and $px$. This gives us that the total area is

$$\int_0^{1/2}8x-px~\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1/2}^{p^{-1/3}}x^{-2}-px~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{1/2}8x~\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1/2}^{p^{-1/3}}x^{-2}~\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{p^{-1/3}}px~\mathrm{d}x$$